# My parser function is not working

Tags: java, parsing

I was designing a simple parser(it works on a simple version of Shunting Yard Algorithm). Here's my code(I haven't dealt with associativity).

```
public class Parser {
    String stack[] = new String[50];
    String res = "";
    int top = 0;
    Operator o1 = new Operator("", 0, 0);

    public String parse(String x) {
        push("(");
        x = x + ")";
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
            if (o1.isNumber(x.charAt(i) + "")) {
                res = res + x.charAt(i);
            } else if (x.charAt(i) == '(') {
                push("(");
            } else if (o1.isOperator("" + x.charAt(i))) {
                if (top != -1) {
                    while ((top != -1) && (o1.isOperator(stack[top]))) {
                        int m = o1.getOperatorIndex(stack[top]);
                        int mp = o1.op[m].prec;
                        int xp = o1.op[o1.getOperatorIndex("" + x.charAt(i))].prec;
                        if (m >= xp) {
                            res = res + stack[top];
                        }
                        top--;
                    }
                }
                push("" + x.charAt(i));
            } else {
                if (top != -1) {
                    while ((top != -1) && (stack[top] != ")")) {
                        if (o1.isOperator(stack[top])) {
                            res = res + stack[top];
                        }
                        top--;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        return res;
    }

    public void push(String m) {
        if (top != 49) {
            stack[top] = m;
            top++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Overflow");
        }
    }
}
```

I guess you won't need the Operator class's code. When I try executing `parse("1+2")`, it just returns `12` and not the + sign. What is wrong? and yes, o[0] is +,o[1] is -,o[2] is*, o[3] is /

Comment: Use some Java debugger to find a reason why it happens, then try to fix your code yourself ;)

Comment: Yes, I tried the debugger. It doesn't help much.